# I don't know what to do because an error occurs --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onload=function() {
    c=document.getElementById('gc');
    cc=c.getContext('2d')
    setInterval(update,1000/30);
    c.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e) {
        p1y=e.clientY-ph/2;
    });
}
```

I am creating a pingpong game but as am fixing it an error occurs and I can't solve it. I have an onload but it doesn't work..

Comment: Do you have an element with ID `gc`?

Comment: Post your relevant HTML, CSS, JS code for us to see. As far as it goes you haven't give us much to work on.

Comment: It seems your javascript is running before the HTML has finished loading.

Comment: with window.onload? that seems unlikely @JYoThI - yes, I know it still is possible if the canvas element is added "dynamically" after this code is run, but really ... do you think that is happening here :p

Answer (score 1):

HTML

Add below code in HTML body

```
 <body>
        <canvas id="gc"></canvas>
</body>
```

JS

```
 <script>
    window.onload=function() {
    c=document.getElementById('gc');
    cc=c.getContext('2d')
    setInterval(update,1000/30);
    c.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e) {
        p1y=e.clientY-ph/2;
    });
   }
</script>
```